# java8_OSGI: NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/collections/MapChangeListener

Tags: java-8, eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle

I just started to develop on OSGI, on Eclipse Kura project and I tried to implement a hashmap Listener:

```java
// Use Java Collections to create the List.
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

// Now add observability by wrapping it with ObservableList.
ObservableMap<String,String> observableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(map);
observableMap.addListener(new MapChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change change) {
        System.out.println("Detected a change! ");
        logerKuraPI("Detected a change! ");
    }
});

// Changes to the observableMap WILL be reported.
observableMap.put("key 1","value 1");
System.out.println("Size: "+observableMap.size());
logerKuraPI("Size: "+observableMap.size());

// Changes to the underlying map will NOT be reported.
map.put("key 2","value 2");
System.out.println("Size: "+observableMap.size());
logerKuraPI("Size: "+observableMap.size());
```

When I run this code in simple main in Intellij IDEA it works fine,however when I implemented in eclipse, OSGI project (Eclipse Kura), I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/collections/MapChangeListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.registerService(InstanceProcess.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.collections.MapChangeListener cannot be found by fileloger_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

without forgetting that when I compile I get no error in eclipse and it recognize the packages, but when I run I get those errors.
and I am using Java8.

Comment: When you use OSGi, you have to declare your dependencies. It looks like you forgot to specify JavaFX.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
I just began with OSGI, when I try to add the JavaFX to dependencies I can't find it in plugin-in selection 
Do I need to install something beside Ef(x)clipse ?
ALso I am using Java8, I thought it's not necessary to declare javafx because it's lready included in java and there is no build errors, only when I run

Answer (score 2):

This part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.collections.MapChangeListener cannot be found by fileloger_1.0.0.qualifier
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

seems to indicate that Equinox is trying to find the class inside your bundle, rather than by delegation. This means that your "bundle" is probably missing some dependency metadata, specifically a package import.

OSGi bundles share API packages through a system of exported and imported packages. An import is *wired* to an export by the OSGi framework as part of the resolution process. This is what it means for your OSGi bundle to be in the **RESOLVED** state rather than the **INSTALLED** state.

All packages that you use in a bundle (except for ones starting `java.*`) *must* be imported by that bundle. In this case the import you would need is for `javafx.collections`. You will find examples that show you how to write an import statement, but you should definitely *not* do this by hand. There are a number of tools out there that will automatically generate a bundle manifest for your OSGi bundle, including the correct package import statements.

If you are using Maven then I would recommend the [bnd-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin), or if you are using Gradle then you can use the relevant bnd plugin for [bnd workspaces](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle#gradle-plugins-for-workspace-builds) or [standalone projects](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle#gradle-plugin-for-non-workspace-builds)

The resulting manifest should end up with an entry like:

```
Import-Package: javafx.collections
```

In addition to doing this you will need to make sure that the `javafx.collections` package is *exported* by something in the framework. Normally this would involve adding a bundle which provides the relevant API package, however I suspect (I'm not a JavaFX user) that JavaFX has to be installed outside the OSGi framework. If this is the case then you will need to add the `javafx.*` API packages as exports from the system bundle (the bundle in the OSGi runtime representing the OSGi framework). This can be achieved using the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` launch property to list the packages (a list of package names separated by `,` characters).

### Update

Your response to this post indicates that you're using Eclipse PDE. PDE isn't as flexible as bnd, and won't do this analysis for you automatically in the build. As a result you can end up with bad metadata if you forget to run through these steps, but it does still offer the ability to automatically determine your bundle's package dependencies in the IDE. The documentation for this is [available from eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fdependencies.htm), but for reference:

1. Go to the Automated Management of Dependencies section of your plugin's manifest editor.
2. Make sure that your compile dependencies are listed in the plug in development classpath list.
3. Make sure that you select the `Import-Package` radio button. `Require-Bundle` promotes tight coupling and high fan out and should be avoided.
4. Any time that you make a change to the code you will need to click the *add dependencies* hyperlink. This will recalculate your package imports for you.

For the future, you may wish to consider using the [Bndtools plugin](http://bndtools.org) for Eclipse to develop OSGi bundles rather than Eclipse PDE. Bndtools usually offers much more sophisticated (and more up-to-date) support for the OSGi specifications than PDE as it builds on top of bnd, and bnd is the reference implementation for several parts of the OSGi specification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply dear Tim, 
That was helpful, 
Sorry for my basic question but I am still find difficulty to choose the tool to generate the Manifest file.
I am not using Maven, or Gradle, 
I am using a plug-in project, any advises or suggestions what tool I should be looking for.
Many thanks

Comment: Post updated to include instructions for what to do in Eclipse PDE